# Anúncio do SOpt no próprio SOpt?

Tags: suporte, bug, status-aceito

Hoje fui testar um browser que não tenho minhas credenciais do site salvas e me deparei com este banner:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso está mesmo certo?

---

## English version

Today I was testing a browser in which I don't have my credentials saved, and I stumbled upon this banner:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Is that right?

Comment: Algo de errado não está certo.

Comment: Cadê as emoções do Facebook quando se precisa delas! Hahaha

Comment: Eu acho que esse banner se aplica as vezes por aqui. Por exemplo, [acabei de ver esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255943/problema-que-nao-consigo-em-c), acho que seria válido mostrar o banner para o OP.

Comment: Isso não devia estar acontecendo. Estou olhando para ele.

Comment: Eu encontrei e vou removê-lo agora.